# Setup DNS on my server so I can put my IPs in as nameservers of my domain provider

Tags: dns, debian, nameserver

Basically, my unmanaged VPS provider doesn't supply me with nameserver which I can use with my domain provider to route domain to my server.

As I've been told:

> You need to configure the custom DNS server in your VPS, to setup the custom nameservers. Please refer the following article that would help:
>
> http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch18_:_Configuring_DNS
>
> Once you configure the nameserver records, please update the domain registrar panel with the custom nameserver details.

I tried to follow this guide but it seems to be a bit outdated, and I am complete newb with non-windows systems. I also scanned the google for other articles which could help me with this problem but, alas, nothing I found was of any value for someone who doesn't know this stuff better than his own pockets.

I realize this is quite a complex thing to do, but maybe there is some way to automate it? Or a better solution, *like a paid service which would act as my nameservers* (this one would be interesting), or even hoped to find some company which "rents" people to do stuff like that. Blah, any help will be appreciated, I am at a complete loss here.

I can follow some of these steps, but then I soon find that half of the files which are mentioned in the article are somehow not existing anywhere on the server which confuses me, and once we get to the point of creating Zone I can't really decipher all the things written there :/.

As per title, my system is Debian 5.0.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider getting a managed VPS/Shared hosting if you're unfamiliar with system administration. You'll be running into **many** issues doing it yourself if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I realize that and it is a very conscious decision. I want to get myself familiar with Unix environment as I believe it will be rather nice addition to my CV actually. Plus I enjoy learning new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking is for a DNS hosting service. There are such services which are either free or paid.  I operate an unmanaged VPS hosting service and many of our customers are not comfortable with operating their own DNS. For this reason, we've found that many of our customers have expressed interest in free DNS hosting, it is certainly not a reason to move away from unmanaged VPS hosting.

Here are some services that we've found our customers to use: [ZoneEdit](http://www.zoneedit.com/), [GrokDNS](http://www.grokdns.com), [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com)

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. I have managed to find a free solution on afraid.org. Thanks for hint!

Answer (score 0):

Many name providers provide Name Servers.  This is usually handled in the same section that you would use for changing your name servers.  You just need to define a host name and providethe IP address.  That should be all that is needed to route the domain to your server. If they allow TXT records you may want to add an SPF record as well.

Unless you are hosting multiple domains or hosts (virtual hosts included) you shouldn't need to run your own server.

If your address is dynamic (I would not expect this to be the case for you), then there are dynamic name services available.  Many of these have scripts which hook into the DHCP service on your server to update your data.